# simultaneously scroll multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm at a brick wall. I have a little project:

**(LINK HAS BEEN REMOVED)**

You can see lots of horizontal scrolls, when you bring the browser down to mobile width, you can scroll horizontally. My problem is, how do I get it so that if you horizontally scroll one item, all the others will follow too? I have tried the following:

```
$('.container').scroll(function(){
    $('.container').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());    
})
```

But I'm getting nowhere fast. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Turns out it does work when you put the code into console AFTER the page has loaded.
I resorted to:

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.container', function(){
    $('.container').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());    
});
```

**UPDATE2**

Big thanks to @George and everyone who answered to point me in the right direction. The tables are loaded with jQuery:

```
$(this).next().load("/availability_Dev/availability_Dev.asp?stuff="+stuff+"");
```

All I had to do was attach my scroll code after the elements were loaded, like so:

```
$(this).next().load("/availability_Dev/availability_Dev.asp?stuff="+stuff+"", function(){
     $('.container').scroll(function(){
         $('.container').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());    
     });
});
```

Comment: The scroll event doesn't bubble up the DOM, so you can't delegate it. You need to attach the handler, to the `.container` elements after they are in the DOM.

Comment: @George Can you put this in terms of code at all? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've already done it. Your code is right, you just need to run it after the items are appended (you need to know when that is, presumably an AJAX callback) and not when the document loads.

Comment: @George I now understand. I'm currently looking for the code that creates the tables and adding the event after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told it works from console after page has loaded. So, try this out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('scroll', '.container', function(){
    $('.container').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());    
  });
});
```

OR use the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.container').scroll(function(){
    $('.container').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());    
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried both example and it still doesn't work.. The first example in your answer is what is currently on my example page

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$('.container').scroll(function(){
  var scrolled = $(this);
  $('.container').each(function() {
    $(this).scrollLeft(scrolled.scrollLeft());    
  })
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That it does, thanks for the input though. Greatly appreciated